# convert an array into a list of objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

All,

I have a dataframe which I am using to extract all unique identifiers as follows:

```
myTradeFrame['coll_cusip'].unique()
```

the output is:

```
array(['BRSUJX0F8', 'BRSU17NB8', '010831BE4', ..., '912828J84',
       '912828R36', '912810RC4'], dtype=object)
```

How can I convert that array into something that looks like this:

```
('BRSUJX0F8', 'BRSU17NB8', '010831BE4', ..., '912828J84',
           '912828R36', '912810RC4')
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Why are you looking to do this?

Comment: i am looking to append that list to an sql query using string concatenation

Comment: How are you doing this? I would recommend asking that broader question as it's likely you will get better/more help with that extra context - maybe you never need to convert to a list!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `myTradeFrame['coll_cusip'].unique()` *returns* a **numpy** array, use `tuple` method.

```
array = myTradeFrame['coll_cusip'].unique()
list = tuple(array)
```

Comment: @SBad, do you need a list or a tuple ?

Comment: I meant a tuple. Sorry I confused you

Comment: @SBad, then just use `tuple` constructor as in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

To get it to return something in the form you asked for (which isn't a list but a tuple), you should use `tuple`:

```
tuple(myTradeFrame['coll_cusip'].unique())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just do this `myTradeFrame['coll_cusip'].unique().tolist()`